# Efficiently invert floats in a list based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have one ndarray of floats (`a`) and one list of 0 or 1 (`b`).  `a` and `b` have the same length, typically 1000. I would like to apply a simple function (such as minus the inverse) to the elements of `a` whose index correspond to 1 in `b`.

The following method takes a bit less than 1 millisecond. Would it be possible to make it faster?

```
import numpy as np

# generate dummy data
n = 1000
a = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=n)
b = np.random.choice(2, 1000)

# map the function
start = time.time()
out = [a[i] if b[i] == 0 else -1/a[i] for i in range(n)]
print time.time() - start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `b` as a mask, and set `a`'s cells accordingly:

```
m = np.array(b).astype(bool)
a[m] = -1 / a[m]
```

Even better, initialise `b` using `np.random.choice`:

```
b = np.random.choice(2, 1000).astype(bool)
```

Now, you don't need the overhead of converting `b` to an array, just use it directly to index `a`:

```
a[b] = -1 / a[b]
```

This runs in

```
22.3 µs ± 501 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: I was going to comment on one of the two things you suggested, because the time for the `astype(bool)` is almost 40% as long as the time for the real code, so better not to do that every time…

Comment: @abarnert _exactly_.

Comment: Great, thank you. Would you call this vectorization?

Comment: @anderstood yes, this is a prime example of vectorised operations in numpy.